# Starting chapters on right side (odd page numbers) in report class doesn't work

Tags: chapters, double-sided

I have tried almost everything. `openright`, `openleft`, `\cleardoublepage`, redefining commands... but nothing works. This is for my thesis. For some reason, my first chapter (and every chapter thereafter) starts on the left side. The page numbering correctly starts at 1 with chapter one, so I don't get it. Usually, odd page numbers should be on the right side, right?

How can I force LaTeX to start my chapters on the right side?
The Table of Contents just before the first chapter correctly starts on the right page (so with a margin on the left). Its two pages long, so the second page of the toc is on the left side (with a margin on the right, as it should be), and the next page is the start of the first chapter, but also starts on the left side.

Is there any specific order I have to consider for commands?
As stated before, `\cleardoublepage` before chapter one just does nothing. Putting `openright` or `openleft` to `\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{report}` also doesn't do anything.

So far, this is what I got:

```
\tableofcontents
\protect\thispagestyle{empty}
\begingroup
  \protect\thispagestyle{empty}
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \clearpage
\endgroup

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}

\chapter{Introduction}
\setcounter{page}{1}
 *text*
```

...

I had to make the table of contents this "weird" because I couldn't find another way to make it start on the right...

I am so sorry, I am not experienced with LaTeX and this is my last straw

Comment: Use `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}`. Chapters will start on odd pages. Clean your code. Use just  `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
text \chapter{Another}
text
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will changing the documentclass affect my document in any other way?

Comment: The design parameters are  different, like margins, so thing will change, but they may be compensated if you want so. `book` is much more appropriate for a thesis. If you already have some chapters done compare the result using one and the other.

Comment: How do you know that the chapter is on the left side? If you look at the margins: if the page is a right page it should  have the large margin on the right, on the outside.